# Simple HTML/CSS website requires a form content placement in an email message

Tags: php, html, forms, email, web

Simple HTML/CSS website requires a page with a form with 3 element and also requires to place a form content in an e-mail message. Can it be done with out PHP or any scripting

Comment: You know such questions generally would bring you many down-votes. At first you might be surprised, but don't be shocked, your question has thousands of answers if you attempted a simple search on the net. You might read about the questions criteria here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: To help you go through, search "PHP Form Processor" in the google

Comment: Thank you, But I searched on net that without PHP etc, its not possible, but requirement is to do so without this

Comment: You have to see if your Hosting panel supports PHP or not (in 95% of cases, well, it supports). Then you should put a php form-processor from net. it is  a file in .php format. The specific setting of the file would be given to you in the site where you have downloaded the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adamant you that you don't want to use PHP, you can always do something like this: (It's not really considered best practice)

```
    <form action="mailto:example@example.com?Subject=Signup%20Info" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
      <p><label for="firstName">First Name:</label><p>
      <p><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required><p><br>
      <p><label for="lastName">Last Name:</label><p>
      <p><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required><p><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Obviously, the `mailto` will redirect your user to their default email provider, with your email address ready to send your desired form variables.. Of course it's not entirely 'automatic'.. But I doubt if it's entirely possible without a server side script since HTML are just tags. 
Of course I would always recommend using a server side script to validate, store and email your form variables versus using this method I've prescribed above. But enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PHPMailer. It is Easy to use.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer